# I want to clone from github to my desktop. But i am still getting some problems with it

Tags: github-pages

C:\Users\Morie Keita>cd desktop

C:\Users\Morie Keita\Desktop>git clone https://github.com/Morie55/Coursera-test.git
Cloning into 'Coursera-test'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Morie55/Coursera-test.git/': Could not resolve proxy: proxyServer

The message above is what they kept asking me.

Comment: Check for answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server-fails-with-request-timed-out

Answer (score 0):

```
unable to resolve proxy
```

Which means that the problem is related to the network. Here are the things you should try

- check that network and DNS server is working. Run `ping google.com`
- If you are in private network like(restaurant, office) the provider may have denied that address
- Try doing so from another network
- temporarily change the DNS server

If none of these worked and you are 100% sure network is right reinstall git or download the repo from browser