# How can I run dbt deps behind a proxy?

Tags: dbt

I have a reference to a dbt hub package in the packages.yml file in my project:

```
packages:
  - package: fishtown-analytics/dbt_utils
    version: 0.6.4
```

When I run dbt deps, this works fine on a machine outside our corporate network but when I run locally I get an error:

```
Encountered an error:
Unable to connect to registry hub
```

presumably because dbt isn't using the proxy.  I have the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables set and these work fine for `pip install` and the like.

Does anyone have any ideas please? I'm running on Windows 7 from inside a git bash prompt (yes I know not ideal, but I have to work with the tools I'm given!)

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this problem as well.  I was able to download the package from the repo and add it as a separate project in a 'libs' folder next to some other projects.  Then in the packages.yml add a local reference.

```
packages:
    - local: '../libs/dbt-utils'
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue.
If you have an SSL certificate for your proxy, you can:

1. Install or upgrade the Python certifi module: `pip install certifi` or `pip install --upgrade certifi`
2. Copy the certificate file to the Python certifi
   module: `cat /<path to certificate>/<certificate file>.pem >> $(python -m certifi)`
3. Update the global pip cert config `pip config set global.cert $(python -m certifi)`
4. Rerun dbt deps to install your packages: `dbt deps`

You can also download your packages manually and add them as local dependencies if that works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If git proxy can be set, as mentioned in this post
[Getting Git to work with a proxy server - fails with "Request timed out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server-fails-with-request-timed-out)

then the following would also work

```
packages:
   - git: "https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils.git"
     version: 1.1.1
```