# Credentials Passed as Plain Text by Git Proxy Setting - Security Risk Question

Tags: git, security

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server-fails-with-request-timed-out) shows how to set your proxy credentials for git.

I want to know about two things after you set your credentials using that method:

1. Does git send your credentials to the proxy over http or https? (My git repository is 'https://*)
2. Are my credentials being sent across the network in the clear?

If yes to question 2, how can I change this so that my credentials are sent over the network more securely?

This is how our proxy server, with a HTTP address, is set up for .gitconfig:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

Can anyone confirm if git would use HTTPS if I were using:

```
git config --global https.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

Comment: How secure is your proxy server? Is it only accessible behind a VPN or is it open to the public? Your proxy server should be running under `https` regardless.

Comment: HI @AdrianJ.Moreno, this proxy can only be accessed by the internal network. (Slightly related to the question --> do you know a particularly good piece of doco/blog around running proxy servers as https?)