# Can't push pull with git via WSL to bitbucket.org on my corp VPN

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using WSL and ubuntu to do push and pulls to a git bitbucket repo and when I do this outside my corp VPN it works just fine.  But when I'm connected to my corp VPN that pushes all my traffic over it, I do a push it asks me for my passphrase, and then just sits there doing nothing.  No commit occurs.

Other people in the organization can do commits on the VPN no problem using WSL and ubuntu so I know its not the network.  I'm at a lose as to why using the VPN stops this from working.

Comment: It'd better provide the detail of "asks me for my passphrase": Is it asking for the passphrase of your SSH key? Or your BitBucket account password? Or the password of your corp proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue may be that some required proxy is not set. It may be happening that git is not using the proxy settings set in Ubuntu.

In this case try enabling proxy directly in git.

See this answer for directions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999/12257301

Answer (score 1):

"passphrase" means you are already using an SSH URL `git@bitbucket.org:...`

And outgoing SSH traffic is generally blocked when initiated from within a corporate VPN network.

I would switch to an HTTPS URL instead (`git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>`), and use a [Git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) to cache your BitBucket user account name and [access token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, a while ago. What I did to fix my problem was to generate an SSH key and set it up on bitbucket.
To generate a key, I usually write the command "ssh-keygen" in windows Command Prompt.

When generated, the key will be located in your ".ssh" folder. Mine is located in "C:\Users\ [my_username] \.ssh" in the file "id_rsa.pub".
I copied the key inside the file and pasted it in my SSH keys list, on my Bitbucket Personal settings.

Here is a link from Bitbucket about setting up a key:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

I hope this could fix your problem.