# Unable to Clone Repo

Tags: git, clone, repo

I am attempting to set up my environment but I keep running into this issue when I am using the git clone command.

I am using a Mac with MacOS Monterey 12.4

Below is the error that I am running into

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Sheshanator/coursera-test.git/': Unsupported proxy syntax in 'proxy.server.com:port'

Comment: Looks like your git `http.proxy` config is incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Git to work with a proxy server - fails with "Request timed out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server-fails-with-request-timed-out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already working behind a proxy, chances are your environment variables `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` are already correctly set.

If you see a value returned in [`git config --global http.proxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999/6309), I would rather unset it, and leave Git use its environment instead of an improperly defined Git configuration.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!!! TYSM!!!! @VonC

Comment: Note to self: this was my 15000th post on [tag:git] tag (since 2008)