# How to point Git to use cntlm

Tags: git, version-control, github, proxy

I am working behind a proxy and I can't access github.com. I read that cntlm can fix this issue. I am still struggling with filling the proxy information.

So my question is, how to point Git to use cntlm to bypass the proxy?

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: version 1.7.11-preview20120710

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need CNTLM for git version 1.7.10 and newer, as it's your case.

See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848870/352672 for details, you can just configure/test this way:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy.com:port
git clone http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-contacts
```

Comment: The advantage of using cntlm is that you aren't storing your password in plain text

Comment: You should store the hashed password in the cntlm configuration file and assign 'http.proxy' as cntlm proxy

Answer (score 28):

In case you actually would want to use CNTLM, it would be configured to git like a regular proxy.

So where you would specify your NTLM proxy like this:

```
git config --global https.proxy https://user:password@proxy.com:port
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy.com:port
```

For CNTLM, you'd just specify your port where CNTLM would be listening at, using localhost:

```
git config --global https.proxy https://127.0.0.1:port
git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:port
```

I have it running on local port 3128, so for me it is

```
git config --global https.proxy https://127.0.0.1:3128
git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

Even if NTLM proxy is supported by git, you might not want to use it that way as it stores your user/pass in clear text. With CNTLM, you have the possibility of using a centralized location where [password can be stored as encrypted](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/cntlm_manual.pdf).

Comment: If you are using CNTLM, make sure you point the proxy to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, as suggested. In Windows, it appears that localhost points first to the IPv6 address, which CNTLM doesn't listen to. As such, git will wait until the timeout (several minutes) before switching to the IPv4 address.