# Git asking the password for Internet connection

Tags: git, bash, github

Git for Windows (Git Bash), OS Windows 7. Computer is in the domain of company.

For opportunity of getting GitHub repositories I added these settings in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://HYPROSTROY\\Developer:my_password@proxy2:8080

[https]
    proxy = https://HYPROSTROY\\Developer:my_password@proxy2:8080
```

It works fine, when I launch something like

```
git clone https://github.com/nunit/nunit.git
```

But I don't want to save my password in the `.gitconfig`. I want Git Bash asking me about my password (it is more safe). How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to point Git to use cntlm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230420/how-to-point-git-to-use-cntlm)

Comment: You can use something like CNTLM (see above link) to avoid the password in the proxy URL.

Comment: @nwinkler no, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Can you please clarify which password we are talking about? The one in the proxy URL, or the one for the GitHub repo?

Comment: Do you have to use https or could you use ssh or direct git protocol?

Comment: @nwinkler, the password of my Windows login, which I use for login on my computer which is located on the domain.

Comment: That's the one you use in the proxy URL in `.gitconfig`, right? If so, there's no way to have Git ask you about that. You either have to keep it in `.gitconfig` like above, or use something like CNTLM (see the above link).

Comment: @Douglas Leeder, I want to have safe opportunity to download repositories from GitHub. To me it isn't important, which it will be the protocol. Unfortunately, I haven't experience with protocols working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried for **Git for Windows 1.9.5** (newest version for Windows from [here](https://git-scm.com/)) such variants of proxy settings in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[http]
  proxy = http://@proxy2:8080
[https]
  proxy = https://@proxy2:8080
```

but it doesn't work for that (v1.9.5) version of Git.

I uninstalled v1.9.5 and installed **Git for Windows Git-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate** from [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases). I see, this settings works fine for Git for Windows Git-2.4.5.1-4RC!

So, I can don't save my password in `.gitconfig` file if I use **Git for Windows Git-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate** instead of **Git for Windows 1.9.5**.