# Yocto - fetch private repo using https

Tags: github, yocto, bitbake

Hello stackoverflow community,

I'm working with Yocto 2.2 (Morty) and I would like to configure a recipe that fetch a private github repo using https protocol. I can do it with ssh but my constraint is to be machine-independant so https it better.

I'm expecting bitbake, when performing the do_fetch() feature, to ask me for my username and password but couldn't get this result yet.

My recipe is configured like this:

```
SRC_URI = "gitsm://github.com/ORGANISATION/my-depot.git;branch=master;protocol=https"
```

Running bitbake gives me the following error:

```
Fetcher failure: [...] git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote https://github.com/ORGANISATION/my-depot.git failed with exit code 128, output: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

However, if I copy paste the following command in my terminal, i get the Username prompt:

```
git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote https://github.com/ORGANISATION/my-depot.git
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Any idea ?

**EDIT**: Note that i also don't want my credentials to appear in the SRC_URI flag.

Comment: You can store the username and password in `.gitconfig`. If you don't want to store password as plain text in `.gitconfig`, use `cntlm`. One useful answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230636/2689839

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion Parthiban, that was helpful. I didn't know git could store credentials. If you want, comment it as an asnwer, i'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sure, I will add it as answer now!

Comment: You can also try https://stackoverflow.com/a/64587959/2443502.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `username` and `password` in `.gitconfig`. If you don't want to store password as plain text in .gitconfig, use `cntlm`.

One useful answer is here: [stackoverflow.com/a/13230636/2689839](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13230636/2689839)

After configuring CNTLM,

```
git config --global https.proxy https://127.0.0.1:port
git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:port
```