# Importing project from Github doesn't work in Aptana

Tags: git, github, aptana

I try to import a project from Github in Aptana via *Import Project* --> *Git Repository as New Project*. I login using my Github Credentials and it lists my repositories. I choose a repository to import.

But then it hangs on `Resolving deltas: (6/6), 100% done.`

I already tried to download Git for Windows and point Aptana to that Git executable, but it doesn't change anything.

EDIT:

I just found out that something similar happens when I connect an existing project to the Github repo.
When pushing or pulling, Aptana hangs on `Launching delegate...`.

Comment: Yep I get the same behavior for git pull and git push. the only thing i can seem to do from the Aptana GUI is git commit's. Then I use the terminal within Aptana to do the git push, git pull. Bottom line seems like it's just simply not working.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to try first is to clone the repo in command line (with [Git For Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/)) and then import the project in Aptana.

If the clone doesn't work, then you need to investigate what is (partially cloned), as in this [blog post](http://hoonzis.blogspot.fr/2012/10/git-stops-after-unpacking-objects-or.html):

- check what [`git fsck`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) returns,
  For instance, this [blog post](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.fr/2012/12/git-hangs-after-resolving-deltas.html#disqus_thread) suggests using `git merge`, but also adds in the comments:

> Since the pack files have been downloaded correctly all you need to do is to interrupt the process with Ctrl+C, do a `git fetch` to fetch branch information from the remote repository and checkout the master (or any other) branch again with a `git checkout master`

- see if there is a proxy issue (like [switching from NTLM authenticated proxy to cntlm](http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/setting-git-to-work-behind-ntlm-authenticated-proxy-cntlm-to-the-rescue/))
- check, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14748815/6309), what [`git verify-pack`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack) returns.

---

[Nicholas Dipiazza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174024/nicholas-dipiazza) confirms the issue [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702096/importing-project-from-github-doesnt-work-in-aptana/23709211?noredirect=1#comment38915187_23709211):

> I use mysysgit - same problem with any git client I try and use on Windows.
>   Seems like as soon as you run git pull or git push, it will hang on "`Launching Delegate`".  It's clearly a defect.
>   **Using the terminal and then running the commands that freeze up is the work-around**.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

I tried cloning the repo with Git for Windows (actually, that's what I use now, since Aptana doesn't work). Git for Windows is working great, no problems whatsoever. But when I try to push/pull with Aptana (after importing the project), it hangs again.

I tried killing git.exe, but Aptana will still hang. I need to kill Aptana too. `git fsck` doesn't say there're any dangling commits.

I don't think there's a proxy issue (I don't use a proxy, as far as I know).

`git verify-pack` needs a *pack number* as argument. I don't know what I should fill in. (I'm new to Git ;))

Comment: @Compizfox what version of msysgit (Git for Windwos) are you using? And what version of Aptana? Maybe Aptana requires a certain version of git For Windows to properly work?

Comment: Aptana comes with its own version of Git. I already tried using another version but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I use mysysgit - same problem with the Git Team functions within Aptana studio. I have only tried Windows. Seems like as soon as you run git pull or git push, it will hang on "Launching Delegate." It's clearly a defect. The work around is to just use the terminal within aptana and run the git commands yourself.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.