# git push and git pull stopped working

Tags: git, github

When I do `git push -u origin master myBranch`

git gets stuck at: **remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (35/35), completed with 10 local objects.**

However if I go to github I can see my new push and create a pull request.

Also if I go `git pull` nothing happens. I dont know why, I have not changed any settings and I am the owner/only user to the project. I have tried to update my ssh keys but no luck

Comment: try to: `git pull origin myBranch`. "However if I go to github I can see" so, you can or can't? because you wrote that "git push stopped working"

Comment: @MegaTron the same thing happens. I am using git in my console and it freezes at **Resolving deltas** I also tried to download the github desktop client and clicking on sync it just loads and never stops.

Comment: Please see on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473341/git-clone-with-ntlm-proxy-hangs-after-resolving-deltas)

Comment: What version of Git are you using, on which OS?

Comment: @VonC git version 2.10.1

Comment: On Windows, I presume?

Comment: @VonC macOS Sierra

Comment: @MegaTron I tried the post you linked but no luck