# capistrano behind http proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Is there a way to set http proxy for capistrano ?

I have a deployment server behind proxy, capistrano just hangs while fetching from the github repository with https  protocol.

How can I tell capistrano to use the proxy server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gateway option, when accessing your remote server through a proxy

```
set :gateway, "proxy-user@100.200.300.400"
ssh_options[:keys] = "~/.ssh/your-key"
```

Make sure you have added your remote servers ssh key into your github repo deploy keys.

You can also try the forward_agent option to make the remote server use your local machine ssh key to access github.

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it helps only to connect to server and does not solve the problem of inaccessible repo :(

Answer (score 0):

Configure git itself to use a proxy.  As a user on the deployment server, use git directly to access github via the proxy. Setting $http_proxy seems to be the trick:

[How do I pull from a Git repository through an HTTP proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy)

Setup the deployment user's environment correctly and it should allow git to work.