# Configuring iTerm and Git to use a proxy on OS X

Tags: macos, proxy, socks, iterm

I am successfully connecting to the internet using an application called tether for a jailbroken iphone.  (I know there's better options now).

My iphone is connected to my laptop's wifi "device network".

I have in my OS X network settings a location called iphone and the proxy is configured to use the correct IP and port for the phone.

I can browse the internet using Chrome over http and https perfectly.

iTerm cannot ping google.  Git cannot pull.  I've googled for days and don't see anything "easy" or that I understand.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Command-line tools usually only support HTTP proxy. For providing a HTTP proxy out of a SOCKS one you have Privoxy. After you've set up Privoxy you have an HTTP proxy. In terminal usually saying `export http_proxy=ip:port` is enough for most applications. For Git specifically consult [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy).

But if that's too much for you, you can use [sshuttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy). It transparently transfers **all** your connections through a SOCKS proxy. That is, all the connections in your computer, and after that you don't have to change proxy settings for your GUI apps.

I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as my package manager in Mac, and both Privoxy and sshuttle are available in it.

Comment: Is it possible to use both? I use privoxy for content filtering, but I would like to use sshuttle for VPN when I travel. I would very much like to chain them together.

Comment: `sshuttle` was perfect for my use case

Comment: I am running sshuttle.But my terminal still not go by proxy

Answer (score 0):

what I am to do now is export the proxy setting, write the proxy in `.zshrc` like this:

```
alias proxy='export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890'
```

when I want to use the proxy, just run `proxy` command in iTerm.