# Proxy through Cntlm: why git clone hangs?

Tags: git, proxy

I was able to set cntlm (see its [sourceforge project](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)) to our corporate proxy and browser works through it. Both on http and https.
But when I try to run `git clone -v https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs.git`, it sends several initial packages and hangs. Resulting `.git` directory is about 14kb.

On the contrary when I set it directly in git via:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://domain\\\login:password@our-proxy-server:8088
```

everything works well.

Do you have any suggestions?
Or probably some proposal how to connect git to repositories without putting password in plaintext configs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems it is a bug in Cntlm: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3106663&group_id=197861&atid=963162

Pity.

**UPD:** just released 0.92 version handles this situation correctly. At least author claims so :)

**UPD2:** 0.92.3 works, I [checked](http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/setting-git-to-work-behind-ntlm-authenticated-proxy-cntlm-to-the-rescue/).

Comment: Good catch on the bug report. +1

Comment: Btw, there's a mention about similar local proxy called ntlmaps works in this scenario. Probably worth a try... but not right now. I'm full with proxies today :)

Answer (score 1):

Git usually hangs when there is some I/O expected during this proces. In your case, the username and password.
Once you set http.proxy (or [%http_proxy% like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy)), git should try to get those login information in `$HOME/.netrc` (or [`%HOME%/_netrc` on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows))

The login information will still be in plain text, but in a file only readable by you. If the https protocol works, that information won't be in plain text over the network.

Comment: Yep, I read that question before posting, thanks. It is my last resort actually - to read and set HTTP_PROXY in script just before running git's sh.exe from msysgit. So I won't have passwords in plaintext but will type them each time I need git.
Cntlm allows me to set just password hash in its config which is far better for me as I need to setup git on windows box in the domain where not only I have admin rights.

Comment: @Ivan: so `_netrc` wouldn't be a good solution for you? I use it all the time, except I define `%HOME%` (which isn't defined by default on Windows, by the way) to an external drive (not a drive on my computer), which is protected to be read only by me. That way, even if I have to change workstation, I still have access to my `%HOME%/_netrc` file.

Comment: Well, Domain Administrator will have access to this folder anyway. It is somewhat paranoid, I know :) But I haven't different passwords for everything and everywhere so prefer never to store them plaintext.

Comment: @Ivan: in that case, you can a wrapper for the git push which will: a/ decode the `username/password` from an encrypted source of your choice, generate the `_netrc` file, do the git push, ** [securely erase](http://superuser.com/questions/86824/how-to-secure-delete-file-or-folder-in-windows) ** the `_netrc`. And here you have it, no more "plain text" information ;)

Comment: Well if there's some util that doing this - I would have been happy :)
Cntlm's approach though seems simpler.