# config git proxy through 127.0.0.1:8087

Tags: git, proxy

I can't git clone https://code.google.com/my-repo,
so I want set git through my local client proxy 127.0.0.1:8087.
How to config?
Thank you.

Comment: "I can't git clone https://code.google.com/my-repo" Why not?

Comment: @Gerry: oh,sorry.my-repo is not a real repo,just as an example.

Comment: @Gerry: You can go to my repo:hh-hello-world,just as the name,it is a test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `https_proxy` environment variable before cloning.  For example:

```
export https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8087
git clone https://wherever/whatever.git
```

... as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy) and in the comments on [GitHub's announcement of Smart HTTP support](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support).

Comment: Roughly speaking, if you just do `https_proxy=whatever` that value will only be available in the current shell - the `git clone` command will not have that environment variable set in its environment.  If you do `export https_proxy=whatever`, however, that environment variable will also be set in the environment of subsequent commands invoked from the shell.  The documentation for `export` in bash can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#index-export-115).

Comment: @HuangheWoo: no problem.  Since this answer turned out to be helpful for you, it's conventional on Stack Overflow to accept it by clicking on the tick beside the answer.