# How do I configure go command to use a proxy?

Tags: go

I want to run `go install` to install the [tour](http://tour.golang.org/#2), but I can't find the option to use a proxy for internet access. I don't need this just for the tour but for developing in Go in general.

How do I configure Go to use a proxy.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Go programs understand environment variables `http_proxy` and `no_proxy`, but that's not enough because `go get` uses source control managers for retrieving code. So you have to set HTTP proxy settings for your SCM too. Use [this](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#http-proxy) for Mercurial and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406766/165293) for Git.

`http_proxy` value can be like `http://user:password@host:port/`. User, password, and port parts are optional. `no_proxy` is a comma-separated list of servers that should not be connected through proxy. Its value can be like `foo.com,bar.net:4000`.

You can set these environment variables in your `bash_profile`, but if you want to limit their usage to `go`, you can run it like this:

```
$ http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080 go get code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt
```

If that's what you always want, set this alias to avoid typing proxy part every time:

```
$ alias go='http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080 go'
```

From now on you can use `go` normally, but it uses your HTTP proxy.

Comment: mercurial uses the http_proxy environment variable, too.

Comment: @Meow Best was is to use a tool like `privoxy` or `torsocks` to provide it as an HTTP proxy to the tools.

Comment: For https proxy, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059670/how-to-set-proxy-for-command-prompt

Comment: For other proxy such as socks, I guess you can set it in IE options for Windows platform. But I didn't tested that.

Comment: `set http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080` and  `set https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080`  if you are on Windows.

Comment: Sometimes for special character https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651270/410439

Comment: plz do not forget `https_proxy=`

Comment: seems only `http_proxy` not enough, `https_proxy` also need, @ ubuntu 20, go 1.14

Comment: if you are using socks5 proxy on linux ubuntu , i had success with `https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8080 go get ...`

Comment: if you are using `go get`, `go mod tidy` etc all requests goes through Go proxy `GO_PROXY` which by default is: https://proxy.golang.org, you can specify `GO_NO_PROXY` to go directly to specified url. `HTTP_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` are two different variables and they are used in http transport.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows command line:

`set http_proxy=http://[user]:[pass]@[proxy_ip]:[proxy_port]/
set https_proxy=http://[user]:[pass]@[proxy_ip]:[proxy_port]/`

...then navigate to https://github.com/ and download the GitHub certificate (I set the name as `goland_cert.cer`)

...now execute the OpenSSL command to export this to PEM format

`openssl x509 -inform der -in goland_cert.cer -out goland_cert.pem`

...finally set the certificate in git global config

`git config --global http.sslCAInfo C:/Users/[User]/certs/golang_cert.pem`

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
alias go='http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1081/ https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1081/ no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1 go'
```

Note: for someones, protocol may be different `https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1081`

Comment: https_proxy works for my go install

Answer (score 5):

you can also map http requests to socks5 traffic by using https://github.com/cyfdecyf/cow/

very handy if you are blocked by GFW

Comment: It's better to add some detail that facilitates `go get` command

Answer (score 4):

Add `GOPROXY` variable name and Variable value as `your proxy` in the System variable. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You may want check  https://github.com/hmgle/graftcp,

```
$ graftcp-local/graftcp-local -h
Usage of graftcp-local/graftcp-local:
  -config string
        Path to the configuration file
  -listen string
        Listen address (default ":2233")
  -logfile string
        Write logs to file
  -loglevel value
        Log level (0-6) (default 1)
  -pipepath string
        Pipe path for graftcp to send address info (default "/tmp/graftcplocal.fifo")
  -service string
        Control the system service: ["start" "stop" "restart" "install" "uninstall"]
  -socks5 string
        SOCKS5 address (default "127.0.0.1:1080")
  -syslog
        Send logs to the local system logger (Eventlog on Windows, syslog on Unix)
```

If you already have shadowsocks listening on 1080, then you don't need provide any paramaters, just run `graftcp-local`, to proxy go get

```
$ ./graftcp go get -v golang.org/x/net/proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git config [--global] http.proxy http://proxy.example.com:port
git config [--global] https.proxy http://proxy.example.com:port
```

see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoGetProxyConfig

Comment: I really wonder why - in my case go-dep - uses the git proxy value and not the env-variables - thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the Go command setting some variables in the Win10 system.

[Here ("Using the cf CLI with a Proxy Server")](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html#:%7E:text=The%20https_proxy%20environment%20variable%20holds,depends%20on%20your%20operating%20system.) you can find the information described below, with images. Also you can read information about:

- Format of https_proxy
- Use SOCKS5 with cf v3-ssh
- Set https_proxy in Mac OS or Linux

I included in this answer only information about W10 because is the one I tested.

## Windows 10

Set the new path variable.

- From the search box, type in `path`
- Select and open "Edit the system environment variables (control panel)".
- "System properties" window will open.
- Select "Advanced" tab.
- Press "Environment Variables" button, a window with the same name will open.
- In "System Variables" section, press the "New" button. "New System Variable" window will open.
- You'll now add the needed variable, fill the fields as follows:

  - Variable name: `https_proxy`
  - Variable value:`http://yourUserName:userNamePassword@yourIPaddress:port`

### Lastly...

I tested the installation command line for go.

Open the console, and type in: `go install github.com/isacikgoz/gitbatch/cmd/gitbatch@latest`

That's an example from this project: https://github.com/isacikgoz/gitbatch

This worked on my particular W10 19043 system.