# How to local test gae golang urlfetch through proxy?

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, localhost, go, urlfetch

My urlfetch client works fine when deployed to appspot. But local testing (dev_appserver.py) through proxy has issue. I can't find any way to set proxy for urlfetch.Transport.

How do you test urlfetch behind proxy locally?

Answer (score 5):

> http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/overview

Got this error message when testing PayPal OAuth on GAE dev_appserver.py (works in production when compiled)

```
const url string = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
const username string = "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp"
const password string = "EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp"

client := &http.Client{}        

req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, strings.NewReader("grant_type=client_credentials"))
req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)
req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en_US")
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

As you can see, Go App Engine breaks http.DefaultTransport
(GAE_SDK/goroot/src/pkg/appengine_internal/internal.go, line 142, GAE 1.7.5)

```
type failingTransport struct{}
func (failingTransport) RoundTrip(*http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return nil, errors.New("http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine. " +
        "See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/overview")
}

func init() {
    // http.DefaultTransport doesn't work in production so break it
    // explicitly so it fails the same way in both dev and prod
    // (and with a useful error message)
    http.DefaultTransport = failingTransport{}
}
```

This solved it to me with Go App Engine 1.7.5

```
    transport := http.Transport{}

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &transport,
    }       

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, strings.NewReader("grant_type=client_credentials"))
    req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en_US")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to use call "client.NewRequest" not "http.NewRequest"

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but did you try [setting the proxy variables](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface)

> In a Unix or Windows environment, set the http_proxy, or ftp_proxy
>   environment variables to a URL that identifies the proxy server before
>   starting the Python interpreter. For example (the '%' is the command
>   prompt):
>
> % http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128"
>
> % export http_proxy

Comment: I do have them setup. It's a golang app using browser ID for login. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the default proxy then the transport is implemented as

```
var DefaultTransport RoundTripper = &Transport{Proxy: ProxyFromEnvironment}
```

setting the environment variable when launching go should solve the problem.

See also this other question: 
[How do I configure Go to use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383299/how-do-i-configure-go-to-use-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

The [urlfetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/reference) package itself does not honor proxy settings, even in development, because it's not actually doing the URL fetch itself: it sends a request to the (possibly development) app server and asks it to do the fetch.  I don't have the source of `dev_appserver.py` handy, but it should honor the standard proxy variables:

```
export http_proxy='http://user:pass@1.2.3.4:3210/'
```

If you do that before you start `dev_appserver.py`, it will probably just work.

If the above does not work, you should [file an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Go%20defect) and then use the following workaround:

```
func client(ctx *appengine.Context) *http.Client {
    if appengine.IsDevAppServer() {
        return http.DefaultClient
    }
    return urlfetch.Client(ctx)
}
```

This will use the urlfetch API on the production appserver but use the standard `net/http` client otherwise, which [does honor](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) the http_proxy environment variable.