# issues with proxy and Go modules using go get

Tags: git, docker, go

I am trying to get `go` modules from `github`.
For example:

```
go get -v -insecure github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
go get -v -insecure github.com/gruntworks-io/terratest/modules/aws
ect..
```

in a `docker build`. 
I am behind a corporate proxy. I believe I have set them correctly:

```
http_proxy=....
https_proxy=...
```

I get this message: `Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after connect`.

I believe (I could be wrong) it is a proxy issue with accessing the `go` modules from `github`, possibly from forwarding that's taking place.

I have tried a few `git` related settings to see if they help but no success yet.:

```
git config --global http.sslverify false &&\
git config --global https.sslverify false &&\
git config --global http.proxy http://... &&\
git config --global https.proxy http://... &&\
git config --global http.proxyAuthMethod 'basic' &&\
git config --global https.proxyAuthMethod 'basic'
```

I don't think they would have an effect, but I tried for fun anyway. 
I'm open to ideas. One idea is to use `curl` in some way to get the modules and point `go` to the modules manually. I'm not sure if that would work and how.

Comment: What does the `Proxy-Authenticate` response header say? Do you get the same behavior if you issue a GET request with `curl`? Maybe see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383299/how-do-i-configure-go-command-to-use-a-proxy

Comment: so when I curl directly I get a better picture. I get the same error, and it refer's to the forward to the new url (the github address). Is it possible to do a git clone on the site itself and somehow point go to the path locally?