# How can I build a Go project without access to "go get"?

Tags: go

How to provide dependencies for go project, when I can only download the dependencies via browser?

I manually placed dependencies at GOPATH, but still `go build` is trying to reach internet to download dependencies

Comment: The best recipe, IMO, would be to find a new job with a less draconian company.

Comment: Do you know if your company has a HTTP proxy? If yes, you might be able to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385612/561422

Comment: IMHO there are good reasons for the security. The nature of the business itself dictates draconian security.

Yes, we have a proxy. It's part of the firewall..

Comment: I don't know why is this called, off-topic. It is a perfectly valid scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to use [Go Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) to manage a project and its dependencies. Go modules also have the [vendor](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories) feature.

When vendor is enabled, local copy of your dependencies will be stored in `vendor` folder within your project. So then when you transfer the whole source code into the server, you don't need to download the dependencies again, since it's already included in the project.

Comment: I would suggest using go modules to manage vendor now, rather than any of those tools, most of which have been deprecated.

Comment: So I went to the docs for Go Modules. IMO, it's so general as to be without meaning for me. Or maybe I'm stupid.

Comment: @ElIngeniero basically what you need to do is: 1. in your local, run go mod init blablabla inside the project; 2. go get all dependencies; 3. go mod vendor; 4. archive/zip the whole source code; 5. send it to the server; 6. unzip; 7. go build and then run. 8. done

Comment: "go get" does not work on my workstation: there's a whitelist of apps that can do https and neither Go nor Git is whitelisted. I need to download with a browser, and put it somewhere. I tried unzipping to $GOPATH/src/github.com/<dev name>/<pkg name> and then "go build && go install" in the unzipped dir.  But when I went to try to build, go tries to download it again.

Comment: go get is a fundamental tool to get your libraries i suggest you ask for it to be white listed or keeping track of dependencies and their version will be a pain