# How do I configure go to use px proxy?

Tags: go, proxy

I'm looking for a solution to load dependencies for go behind a proxy. My setup is the following.

- I'm running Windows and mainly work with git bash to interact with for example the go command
- I have [px proxy](https://github.com/genotrance/px) setup and running (it works just fine for other tools like pip)
- All my proxy env vars (http_proxy, https_proxy, HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY) are set to http://127.0.0.1:1234 (the px proxy).

I try to run `go get github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang` or `go run bar/my_script.go`, but it always returns one of the following messages.

```
go: github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang@v1.3.4: reading https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/@v/v1.3.4.mod: 403 Forbidden
```

---

```
go: finding module for package github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang
xyz.com/foo/bar imports
        github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang: module github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/@v/list": Proxy Authentication Required
```

I already followed the advice from this question: [How do I configure go command to use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383299/how-do-i-configure-go-command-to-use-a-proxy). It didn't help.

Also, I tried `GOPROXY=direct go get -v github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang`. Still the same output.

I would appreciate any tip.