# Unable to Install operator-sdk on linux behind proxy

Tags: go, kubernetes, proxy, operator-sdk

I am trying to install kubernetes operator on linux machine as it has corporate proxy its unable to download packages.

followed below link to install.
https://www.velotio.com/engineering-blog/getting-started-with-kubernetes-operators-helm-based-part-1

commands:
go get -d github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk

cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk

git checkout master

make dep

make install

failing at make install

please let me know how to configure proxy

Comment: Did you see [this tutorial](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/)? Did it help?

Comment: You can follow the steps defined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385612/6756913