# Reset git proxy to default configuration

Tags: git

I installed Socat to use the Git Protocol Through a HTTP CONNECT Proxy, then I create a script called `gitproxy` in your bin directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Use socat to proxy git through an HTTP CONNECT firewall.
# Useful if you are trying to clone git:// from inside a company.
# Requires that the proxy allows CONNECT to port 9418.
#
# Save this file as gitproxy somewhere in your path (e.g., ~/bin) and then run
# chmod +x gitproxy
# git config --global core.gitproxy gitproxy
#
# More details at https://www.emilsit.net/blog/archives/how-to-use-the-git-protocol-through-a-http-connect-proxy/

# Configuration. Common proxy ports are 3128, 8123, 8000.
_proxy=proxy.yourcompany.com
_proxyport=3128

exec socat STDIO PROXY:$_proxy:$1:$2,proxyport=$_proxyport
```

then I configured git to use it:

```
$ git config --global core.gitproxy gitproxy
```

Now I want to reset git to the default proxy configurations, how can I do that?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can remove that configuration with:

```
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me .. I used `git config --global --unset http.proxy` and everything is fine

Comment: git config --global --unset http.proxy worked for me as well.

Answer (score 176):

For me, I had to add:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Basically, you can run:

```
git config --global -l
```

to get the list of all proxy defined, and then use "--unset" to disable them

Comment: and for https use git config --global --unset https.proxy

Comment: One annoying thing with `--unset` is that it leaves the section heading, so you can end up with multiple empty `[http]` sections polluting your `.gitconfig`. Use `config --global --remove-section http` to remove the entire `[http]` section including the heading.

Answer (score 23):

Edit .gitconfig file (Probably in your home directory of the user ~) and change the http and https proxy fields to space only

```
[http]
    proxy = 
[https]
    proxy =
```

That worked for me in the windows.

Answer (score 20):

**On my Linux machine :**

```
git config --system --get https.proxy (returns nothing)
git config --global --get https.proxy (returns nothing)

git config --system --get http.proxy (returns nothing)
git config --global --get http.proxy (returns nothing)
```

I found out my https_proxy and http_proxy are set, so I just unset them.

```
unset https_proxy
unset http_proxy
```

**On my Windows machine :**

```
set https_proxy=""
set http_proxy=""
```

Optionally use [setx](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) to set environment variables permanently on Windows and set system environment using "/m"

```
setx https_proxy=""
setx http_proxy=""
```

Answer (score 12):

Remove both http and https setting by using commands.

`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

`git config --global --unset https.proxy`

Answer (score 6):

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Comment: It appears this answer was provided by @sramij three years earlier. How is this answer different then sramij answer? Unfortunately, the only thing we can do at the moment is flag this answer as spam. Also see [New flag reason for “Pointless Answer” for “Me too” type answers](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1016/new-flag-reason-for-pointless-answer-for-me-too-type-answers).

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Powershell commands to set the Proxy on windows machine doing the below helped me.

To **unset** the proxy use: 
1. Open powershell
2. Enter the following:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(“HTTP_PROXY”, $null, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(“HTTPS_PROXY”, $null, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

To **set** the proxy again use: 
1. Open powershell
2. Enter the following:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(“HTTP_PROXY”, “http://yourproxy.com:yourportnumber”, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(“HTTPS_PROXY”, “http://yourproxy.com:yourportnumber”, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Answer (score 0):

If running

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

gives a warning:

> http.proxy has multiple values

and none of the proxies are removed, then add "-all" in the command:

```
git config --global --unset-all http.proxy
```

to successfully remove all proxies.

You can check it with:

```
git config --global --list
```