# How to Use Gitproxy for Custom SSH

Tags: git, ssh, git-config

How can I use gitproxy to connect with custom ssh options for a particular remote / domain ?

Answer (score 0):

Custom ssh means an url like `myssh:myrepo`, with a `~/.ssh/config` file having an entry like:

```
Host myssh
HostName aserver.com
User auser
Port aportnumber
```

So you could [set a gitproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11265463/6309) for that "domain":

```
git config --global core.gitproxy "ssh for myssh"
```

But that shouldn't be necessary, since a remote url like myssh:myrepo would be interpreted by git as an ssh url anyway.