# Git: How to remove proxy

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push to my repo but receiving an error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myrepo.git/': Could not resolve proxy: --list
```

I already changed the proxy settings :

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

my global config settings are:

```
push.default=simple
http.sslverify=false
url.https://.insteadof=git://
credential.helper=cache --timeout=3600
```

But still getting this error? How can I solve this?

Comment: what does `git config --list | grep proxy` tell you about your proxy settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset git proxy to default configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265463/reset-git-proxy-to-default-configuration).

Comment: git config --global --unset https.proxy  For https configuration

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Check your enviroment:

```
echo $http_proxy
echo $https_proxy
echo $HTTPS_PROXY
echo $HTTP_PROXY
```

and delete with `export http_proxy=`

Check your git config files for a proxy:

```
git config -l --show-origin | grep "proxy"
```

You can unset a global proxy `<user_directory>/.gitconfig`:

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Or a proxy from the local config `.git/config`:

```
git config --unset http.proxy
git config --unset https.proxy
```

It is also possible that the proxy is from a system config file.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I got the error `Unsupported proxy syntax in <proxyserver>:<port>` when I tried to clone a repository and could solve the problem by deleting the proxy setting: `export http_proxy=`, `export https_proxy=`, `export HTTPS_PROXY=`, and `export HTTP_PROXY=`. After deleting the settings I could clone the repository without problems.

Comment: Please consider adding `git config -l --show-origin` as suggested by @phani-rithvij @vonc and jiang-flori. This eliminates guesswork and enables you to see where the proxy config is coming from.

Comment: Well done. This is working like a charm.

Answer (score 14):

Did you already check your proxys here?

```
git config --global --list
```

or

```
git config --local --list
```

Answer (score 7):

You config proxy settings for some network and now you connect another network. Now have to remove the proxy settings. For that use these commands:

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Now you can push too.
(If did not remove proxy configuration still you can use git commands like add , commit and etc)

Answer (score 5):

You can list all the global settings using

```sh
git config --global --list
```

My proxy settings were set as

```
...
remote.origin.proxy=
remote.origin.proxy=address:port
...
```

The command `git config --global --unset remote.origin.proxy` did not work.

So I found the global `.gitconfig` file it was in, using this

```sh
git config --list --show-origin
```

And manually removed the proxy fields.

Comment: Your answer is very useful and `git config --global --unset remote.origin.proxy` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is in the case if first answer does not work
The latest version of git does not require to set proxy it directly uses system proxy settings .so just do these

```
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
```

in some systems you may also have to do

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

if you want to permanantly remove proxy then

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
```

Comment: is it global or local ?

Comment: Thanks, git config --unset https.proxy didn't work for me, unset https_proxy removed the proxy and I was able to connect to git.

Comment: It is global, but not permanent.It removes proxy for the current terminal session

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
git config -l --show-origin
```

We can find the file location, and delete:

```
[remote "origin"]
        proxy =
        proxy = 127.0.0.1:(proxy http port number)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers have mentioned the proxy settings in git itself.
However, if you ever set an **SSH proxy** for your remote repository in your ssh settings in files like `~/.ssh/config` etc., git uses the config to perform ssh connections.

For me, I configured an SSH proxy for all my GitHub repos:

```
# proxy github
Host github.com
  User git
  ProxyCommand nc -x $PROXY %h %p
```

Remove the settings solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have environment variable that could still define a proxy (picked up by `curl`, even if the git config does not include any proxy setting anymore):

```
HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY
```

Comment: I had these `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` on the environment variable in Windows 7 and removed those, but the problem still exist and git shows:`Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8580: Connection refused` error.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde it looks like you still have a proxy defined somewhere: do you see in in `git config -l`?

Comment: It didn't show anything. But I've solved my problem with setting `[http] proxy=` and `[https] proxy=` in `C:\Users\Username\.gitconfig` and `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Yes, these days, a `git config -l --show-origin` can help track those settings.

Comment: after deleting Windows environment variables you should relog to ensure they really disappear from all open instances of Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Some times, local config command won't show the proxy but it wont allow git push due to proxy. Run the following commands **within the directory** and see.

```
#git config --local --list
```

But the following commands displays the proxy set to local repository:

```
#git config http.proxy
#git config https.proxy
```

If the above command displays any proxy then clear it by running the following commands:

```
#git config https.proxy ""
#git config https.proxy ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --unset http.proxy
http_proxy=""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already unset the proxy from global and local level and still see the proxy details while you do

```
         git config -l
```

then unset the variable from system level, generally the configuration stored at below location

```
 C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

if you used  `remote.origin.proxy`( check it by using `git config --global -l` ) ,then use  `git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.proxy`  .

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just the IPV6 causing this error ! after uncheking the IPV6 option on the network adapter (and just using IPV4), the error disappeared !

Answer (score 0):

For `windows` I used ( set to empty value )

```
set https_proxy=
set http_proxy=
```

I seems that git uses these global variables too