# Enterprise proxy blocking yarn, npm and git

Tags: macos, homebrew

So I have been having some issues with git, npm and brew. It seems to be related to the enterprise proxy I used before. I am not using this computer anymore behind that enterprise proxy but it seems I haven't cleared all the proxy settings. I have cleared all the instances I can find in "Network settings" but there seems to be more. Anyone got a good idea for how to find where my proxy is kicking in and how to remove it? An example of how it looks in the Terminal

brew install yarn

==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-7.7.2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz

curl: (7) Failed to connect to proxy.enterprise.com port 123: Operation timed out

Answer (score 0):

To delete git proxy settings, [try doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265463/reset-git-proxy-to-default-configuration):

```
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

You can also see all proxies defined by doing:

```
git config --global -l
```

And then you'll know which ones to delete.

npm has it's own proxy settings [which you can delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228995/how-to-clear-https-proxy-setting-of-npm):

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

For brew, make sure `http_proxy` isn't set in your envirionment variables.

That is, something that looks like this:

```
http_proxy=http://<proxyhost>:<proxyport> brew install $FORMULA
```

or

```
ALL_PROXY
```

Comment: Thanks! The git ones didn't work for some reason but when I tried git config --global http.proxy "" it worked. However the brew one still isn't working.