# Git tries resolve a proxy which hasn't been set

Tags: linux, git, proxy

I set http_proxy in my /etc/environment file but I removed it recently. I am trying to checkout a project from git but I am always getting following error.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/yyy.git/': Could not resolve proxy: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I double checked my system proxy and git proxy setting using following commands but they do not show me any applied proxy setting. How can I solve this issue?

```
env | grep proxy
git config -l | grep proxy
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset git proxy to default configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265463/reset-git-proxy-to-default-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

`git config --global --unset http.proxy` resolved the issue