# How can I troubleshoot git pull

Tags: git

I cloned a https github repository while at work. At work I can pull/push without issues. However, when I go home 'git pull' just hangs. Wireshark doesn't show any traffic going out over https. I don't have any proxy settings defined in git.

Is there anyway to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you even see a TCP SYN?  What about a DNS request?  Can you ping the server?  What about traceroute?

Comment: No I don't see a TCP SYN when I get pull, not watching DNS request 'nslookup github.com' returns 207.97.227.239. I can 'telnet github.com 443' successfully.

Comment: Is this a *different* clone from the one at work, or did you create the clone at work and then bring home the repo on a USB stick or something? Can you create a new clone from home?

Comment: This is the same clone from the one at work. It is on my laptop, no USB involved. git clone using https hangs too. git clone over ssh works fine... but I don't want to have to reclone my repo every time ;)

Comment: Does your OS settings have HTTPS going through a pre-set corporate proxy by default? That could explain the problem, and also why Wireshark doesn't see any specific HTTPS traffic.

Comment: My proxy settings are using a .pac file. Web browsing does not go through the proxy when at home. Does msysgit honor the OS proxy settings? Presumably wireshark isn't showing any specific HTTPS traffic because there is no outgoing HTTPS requests - if I 'telnet github.com 443' that shows up in wireshark.

Comment: Just throwing this out: have you done a `git config --list` to see if anything surprising shows up?

Comment: yeah, so just ran 'git config --list', found an entry for http.proxy that I didn't expect so I removed it, but 'git pull' is still hanging. Which is expected I guess since I'm trying to pull over https.

Comment: Also, nslookup may not reflect your os cache.  You could also try ipconfig /flushdns.  That doesn't make sense to me, but it could be that git is asking your OS cache, and your os cache is saying some funky IP that is not routing like you'd hope.

Comment: 'ipconfig /flushdns' was one of the first things I tried. No joy.

Comment: This thread seems to be abound with suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy.  updating your certs, setting an env var to cause curl to have debug output, and others.  Makes we want you try curl on it's own to same HTTPS url; just so you can see output. (and hope it has same behavior)

Comment: sweet... seems that when I removed http.proxy I didn't realize this was a global setting and it was still there. Did manage to get the http.proxy setting this time and things are working now. ;(

Answer (score 1):

```
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

Then run

```
git pull
```