# VPN Issue: CURL works, WGET works, Git doesn't work

Tags: git, curl, wget, vpn

I'm working on an intranet Suse Linux server and trying to get our Ruby on Rails app installed. The big obstacle right now is getting the server to "git pull" our repo.

To get curl and wget working I had to set up a proxy like such:

```
export https_proxy=https://example.com:911/

export http_proxy=http://example.com:911/
```

Great! Files are downloading, gems are being installed, I'm on my way. However when I use git, over http or ssh, it fails.

What protocol does Git use? Are these related? Ideas?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/

Comment: Git uses `libcurl` to speak to servers via `HTTP[S]`.  So read the thread @Mike pointed you to, especially the answer about setting the `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` to trace cURL requests Git makes.