# How to download a source code of code.google.com

Tags: android, git, opencv, google-code, panorama-control

I am stuck with downloading project code for an android application on code.google.com.
https://code.google.com/p/android-opencv-panorama/
 My college have proxy settings issues while trying to download via terminal using Git. 
Could somebody provide a link or way to do so.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy

Comment: I have tried a lot with terminal and I am exhausted. Is there an alternative?

Comment: if you want to get creative, you could always set up a cloud instance and download/zip/serve the repo from there over ftp or whatever

Comment: i had download it downloaing well no problem with me

Comment: @PintuCorna- how you downloaded it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to try at least:

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
```

Or, for bash session:

```
 export http_proxy=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
 export https_proxy=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
```

Then, for git commands:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
```

Now the git clone should work:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/android-opencv-panorama/
```

---

The [OP mohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783855/mohit) reports that [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) works: it can indeed detect the default proxy settings.

Comment: I installed Egit and it worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @mohit Excellent, I have included Egit in the answer for more visibility.