# Git in Visual Studio 2013 - There is No Remote Configured for this local Repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

My woes with GIT in Visual Studio continue.

This morning, I went to do a Pull and found the option was not even available to me. A message stated

> There is No Remote Configured for this local Repository. Establish the
>   remote by publishing to the URL of an existing empty repository.

Why would I do that if I have been working with an existing NON-empty repository?

The kicker is, I cannot use any other GIT tool to troubleshoot this (e.g. GIT Bash) because authentication fails every time UNLESS I am working through the narrow Visual Studio workflow for GIT.

Like [the last time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21471169/540156), any help would be appreciated. Otherwise, I guess I'm cloning again. My hard drive is dotted with heaps of clones of this repository now. Crazy!

Comment: Why does Git for Windows not authenticate?  Are you talking to an on-premises TFS server or Visual Studio Online?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I think you solved this for me. I ran that command and got 'fatal: bad config file line 1 in .git/config'. So I opened that file in Notepad++ and it was full of nuls (weirdly spelt with only 1 l). I copied and pasted the contents of a cloned config file into that one, and boom, I could do a pull. Thanks!

Comment: Sure - I would still love to know why you're having trouble using the command line tools against your remote repository, though.  Would you mind opening a new question and we can try to get to the bottom of it?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Hi Edward. I create a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21808341/540156). Sorry for delay, I've been in and out all arvo.

Comment: Not at all - thanks @onefootswill - it looks like you're able to connect now!  Please let us know if you have any other problems.