# Authentication Failed - Git Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-gui

I am tying to use GIT Gui with Visual Studio for pushing my project to online repo stored at a sub domain in VisualStudio.com. I am trying to push the changes I have committed.

At authentication page I get an error even though I put correct user name and password.
Not getting whats wrong!!

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808341/unable-to-authenticate-with-git-bash-to-visual-studio-online/21808395#21808395