# Visual studio - git pull causes error

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops, pull

I have a Git repository on Visual Studio Team Services. When I try to pull commits, I get the following error:

> 18 uncommitted changes would be overwritten by merge

I've found some question on SO that recommends committing / stashing / etc. local changes. The problem is that I have no any local changes. Here is what `git status` outputs:

> C:\VS\Project>git status
>
> nothing to commit, working directory clean

There is no local changes. What's more, when I tried to `git pull` via command line tools, but I can't login - my credentials for VS Team Services doesn't work (but I can log via web browser or by VS without any problems).

Whan can I do to pull commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in Visual Studio 2013 through Update 3 that will prevent you from merging in certain circumstances when you have `core.autocrlf` set to `true` yet the files in your repository are incorrectly normalized.  We are comparing the contents of your working folder (which has Windows-style `'\r\n` line endings) to the contents of your repository, which you have claimed (by setting `core.autocrlf=true`) have Unix style `\n` line endings.

If, in fact, your repository contains files with `\r\n` line endings, then we will incorrect report these files as modified in your working directory and prevent the merge.  (We should, of course, be looking at the timestamp in the index and not bothering to test these files at all.)

While this *is* a bug in Visual Studio (and will be fixed in the next Update), it is obscuring the fact that your repository is not configured correctly.  You should configure a `.gitattributes` file and [correct the line endings in your repository](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) to avoid these sorts of problems.

In the meantime, you can use Git for Windows on the command-line to solve this problem, please be sure to [configure alternate credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808341/unable-to-authenticate-with-git-bash-to-visual-studio-online) in [Visual Studio Team Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx).

Comment: Sorry about the bug, by the way.  This is a real annoyance. :(

Comment: Thanks! I've turned on alternate credentials and command-line git works like a chram. Hmm maybe visual studio should configure line-endings for us? Or should print proper warning?  hope it will be changed in next mentioned Update.

Comment: @pwas If you create your repository in VS, it should set up `.gitattributes` in the repository.  (So should GitHub for Windows and many other clients.)  Unfortunately there are a few Git clients that can set up configuration that is not shared by other Git clients, which really ruins the party for everyone.  :(  We're continuing to try to improve this situation though.

Comment: @EdwardThomsoh maybe there is an other bug? My repo was created in VisualStudio, but it looks like the `.gitattributes` was not set propertly. Anyway, thanks for explanations!