# Can't connect to Visual Studio Online via Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, team-explorer

I can log into Visual Studio Online from the web interface but when I try and connect using the same set of credentials via GitBash (`git push origin`) or Visual Studio Team Explorer I get an error.

With Visual Studio its a server error of 500 and GitBash returns `Authentication failed`.

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: Did you set up alternate credentials? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808341/unable-to-authenticate-with-git-bash-to-visual-studio-online

Comment: No I didn't. But I don't want to login via GitBash. I'm happy to stick to Visual Studio but its not working with the credentials I use to login to the website. It used to. Every time I try a push from VS it brings up the log in box but the credentials don't work.

Comment: Are you logging into VSO using a microsoft account or a work account? I've heard of a few folks having trouble connecting with VSO from team explorer if they're using a work account.

Comment: A Microsoft account.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are on on? Can you try enabling alternate creds, as suggested by Edward, and see if it works with GitBash. You will need to use basic auth with GitBash. Is your user id a live.com account? Btw, I just tried connecting with VS 2015 RC and it worked for me..

Comment: I set up alternate creds and now I can push using GitBash but it still doesn't work from Visual Studio because my secondary username is not an email address.

Comment: My primary username is an email address I believe for live.com.