# git clone failing even after setting proxy with username:password

Tags: git

I am trying to clone the RestKit from https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git.
This is what I have done so far:

1. Installed git.
2. Set up the `.gitconfig` file with correct params in `~/`

   ```
   [user]  
       name = myName   
       email = myEmail  
   [http]  
       proxy = http://<username for proxy>:<password for proxy>@PROXY:8080  
       sslverify = false  
   [https]  
       proxy = https://<username for proxy>:<password for proxy>@PROXY:8080
   ```
3. Started the clone command as follows:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git
   ```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cloning into 'RestKit'...  
error: Could not resolve host: (nil); nodename nor servname provided, or not known while accessing https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack  
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
When I replace the http.proxy in the .gitconfig file with
    http://:8080

i.e., without the credentials, then I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'RestKit'...  
error: The requested URL returned error: 407 while accessing https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack  
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Comment: Can you reach the proxy machine (ex: `ping PROXY`)?

Comment: Yes I can. I just tried and I am getting replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out the issue. My password had an '@', due to which anything after the '@' in the password was being considered as the proxy address. Quite simple and dumb but it took me long to figure this out. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, proxies don't work without having the domain first specified. Try adding this to your `.gitconfig`

```
[http]
    proxy = http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@PROXY:8080
```

Also have a further look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy) it might point some things out.

Comment: I have looked at the link that you have pointed out before also. I have set the lower case env variable in same way as I have set the proxy in .gitconfig. i.e., http://uName:uPassword@PROXY:8080.

Comment: Also, Can you tell me where I can find myDomain name? I am sorry if that is a dumb question but I have never needed that before and so I am not aware of where to find it. By the way, I am using an iMac.

Comment: I assume that you need to have a proxy due to your work's network?  if so, then you need to find out from your tech support.

Comment: Yes. I actually found that and just tried the command you have posted. I am still getting the "Could not resolve host" error. :(