# Set proxy for git

Tags: git, proxy

Im using my office network and to connect to the internet I use a proxy.
Im trying to install a plugin using git -

```
git clone https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf.git
```

but I get an error -

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error
```

I have the following details about the proxy : IP address, port number,domain,username,password

How do I configure git to use this proxy?

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pull from a Git repository through an HTTP proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

I had that error before you need [global config file](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)
If you have a proxy with authentication you need to put in it:

```
    git config --global http.proxy http://login:password@our-proxy-server:8088
```

And it just works (with 'git clone http:')
Here is an [example](http://rip747.wordpress.com/2008/09/12/git-clone-over-http-who-knew/)