# Git couldn't resolve proxy

Tags: git, windows-8, proxy

I'm trying to push my changes but keep getting the following error:

```
error: Couldn't resolve proxy ''xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' while accessing http://name:password@site.com:7678/scm/xx/xxx.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Previously I had set up a proxy for an unrelated project on Windows 8 through 'LAN Settings' in 'Internet Options', I removed the proxy but it seems that Git is trying to connect to it for some reason. I never set any proxy options on Git.

I've tried the following:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
git config --local --unset http.proxy
```

Comment: Notice the two single quotes at the beginning of the proxy, weird

Comment: "What and I not allowed to say thanks?" Because it is just noise: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/6309. Please remove the last two lines of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `git config -l | grep proxy` to see if there is any `http.proxy` setting defined anywhere.

And check your `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables: even without git setting in place, those variables could be picked up by git for a `git push`.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=
set HTTPS_PROXY=
```

The idea is to set [those settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14750116/6309) or environment variable with the right url, without double single quotes.

The [OP Carlos Granados](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3421225/carlos-granados) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413760/git-couldnt-resolve-proxy/22421042?noredirect=1#comment34160481_22421042):

> I removed the environment variable '`HTTP_PROXY`'.
>   The Git file did not have those variables set.

Comment: @CarlosGranados did you remove the environment variables? And kept the `git config http.proxy` one in place?

Comment: I removed the environment variable 'http_proxy'. The Git file did not have those variables set.

Comment: @CarlosGranados Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.