# Composer behind proxy not working for symfony project

Tags: symfony, proxy, composer-php

In my workplace network we have to use a proxy. I want to use Composer a to download some package dependencies for my Symfony2 projects. It does not work even after declaring the environment variable with the proxy information. I noticed that we are also unable to revolve any external name using the DNS of the company. And I think that one is the main problem that does not alow us to download with composer.
The truth is that I can not change any thing on those servers or policies of the company.
Do you think that I can do something that can let me resolve those names or access those resources to install the dependencies? 
this is the error:

```
The "http://thirds.packagist.dev/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable)

http://thirds.packagist.dev could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                     

  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. O  

  penSSL Error messages:                                                                                       

  error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure                             

  failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy                                          



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Then the composer.json file is this one:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
 "repositories": [
    {            
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://thirds.packagist.dev"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.4",
    "sylius/resource-bundle": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "*",
    "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Adding composer diag:

```
root@zeus:/home/abel/Documents/http/team# php composer.phar diag
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
Checking HTTP proxy: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: OK
Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: FAIL
Unable to assert the situation, maybe github is down (The "https://api.github.com/repos/Seldaek/jsonlint/zipball/1.0.0" file could not be downloaded: Peer certificate CN=`*.github.com' did not match expected CN=`201.220.215.11'
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy)
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: 


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                     
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenS  
  SL Error messages:                                                                                           
  error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure                             
  failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy                                          



diagnose


root@zeus:/home/abel/Documents/http/team#
```

Also I tried to declared the ip of packagist.org on my etc hosts... and then i notices that the DNS that is used is not the one of my localhost:

```
root@zeus:/home/abel/Documents/http/team# php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information



  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                     
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection t  
  imed out                                                                                                     



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]


root@zeus:/home/abel/Documents/http/team# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
201.220.207.218 zeus.ltu.sld.cu zeus
127.0.0.1       thirds.packagist.dev
127.0.0.1       abel.ltu.sld.cu
87.98.253.214   packagist.org
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
root@zeus:/home/abel/Documents/http/team#
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy

Comment: I do not think that's the same problem

Comment: what about adding packagist.org to your /etc/hosts and route to the correct ip ?

Comment: Please run `composer diag` and add the result to your question. Composer has decent support for the environment variables, and I don't experience any problems using a proxy server, so the problem likely is in your configuration and your local proxy.

Answer (score 5):

I once faced the same issue, and setting the proxy in my terminal solved the problem.

If you're using Windows, enter these commands :

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
```

In Unix system, the command is `export` instead of `set`.

Then you can run `composer update` command.

If you still have problems, it might be git that needs the proxy configuration too.
In your `%HOMEPATH%\.gitconfig`, add the following :

```
[http]
    proxy = http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
```

**EDIT:**

Since you've added the results of `composer diag`, the problem seems to be that your proxy doesn't handle the request_fulluri flag for HTTPS requests.

You can disable this option by setting the environment variable HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI like this (Unix system) :

```
set HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=0
```

Comment: i am using Linux... in Linux I used `export` instead of set. Any way it does not work for my situation...

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy), you may need to set those 2 variables in lowercase too.

Comment: Thanks @mneute :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780165/install-laravel-4-behind-proxy