# Symfony 2 install third party bundle manually

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

My Internet conexion is useless to install a symphony 2 dependency with composer as far as I can say. Is there a way to install a third party bundle manually? I have been looking in Google and I did not find any useful thing so far. About my connection issue, I started [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942967/composer-behind-proxy-not-working-for-symfony-project) thread to try and find a solution to install within this connection. here I am trying to find clues to a solution to install manually.
Regards

Comment: What do you mean with `manually` ? Do you know https://toranproxy.com/ ? You install it locally and it cache/proxy packagist and github. Is free for personal use.

Comment: manually means no composer or any other software to do the job for you... I download, I install and I configure. Driver seat.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 Create under vendor directory the path for bundle :

       `/*like mycompany*/    /*like product-bundle*/     /*like MyCompany*/
  vendor/yourbundlenamespace/your-bundle-name-bundle/YourBundleNameSpace/`
- 2 Go to in the new path and put the content of budle (or clone from github).
- 3* @deprecated 
  Load the reference path on autoload, so go to in

  `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php`

  and put in the array 

  `'YourBundleNameSpace\\YourBundleNameBundle' => array($vendorDir .      '/yourbundlenamespace/your-bundle-name-bundle');`
- 4 Register bundle: go to in 

  `app/AppKernel.php`

and put in the array $bundles the new bundle:
```

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
      //...
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
     //...
     // this is our bundle :)
       $bundles[] = new YourBundleNameSpace\YourBundleNameBundle\YourBundleNameBundle();
    }
```

```

## UPDATE

Point 3: this method is not performance because when update via composer is overwrite, instead, you should do:

-go to on app/autoload.php
and put following code after $loader definition
```
//add customs classes

```
$loader->add('YourBundleNameSpace\\YourBundleNameBundle','vendor//yourbundlenamespace/your-bundle-name-bundle');
```

```