# Install Laravel behind proxy

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, proxy

Im trying to install Laravel on a windows machine.
I followed this guide up to point 11.
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows

I also ran two commands already (which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18852026/2240163)

`set http_proxy=<your_http_proxy:proxy_port>`
 `set https_proxy=<your_https_proxy:proxy_port>`

But on running `composer install` i am met with a message

```
  C:\wamp\www\LARAVEL>composer install
  Loading composer repositories with package information

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL
  : The specified procedure could not be found.

  failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
```

How can I get past the proxy to install Laravel 4.

.
.

**Here in lay the solution**

```
C:\wamp\www\LARAVEL>set http_proxy=http://mnel:******@192.168.20.4:8080
C:\wamp\www\LARAVEL>set https_proxy=https://mnel:******@192.168.20.4:8080
```

I then ran the `install composer` command again and presto!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958700/2240163
Thanks @mneute

Comment: I think its because it was not able to connect to https using proxy can you try this [Composer Behind Firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy)

Comment: No problem !
I'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in lay the solution

`C:\wamp\www\LARAVEL>set http_proxy=http://mnel:******@192.168.20.4:8080`
`C:\wamp\www\LARAVEL>set https_proxy=https://mnel:******@192.168.20.4:8080`

I then ran the install composer command again and presto!

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958700/2240163

Thanks `@mneute`

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue when I ran composer -vvv install. I did it in windows7 computer behind a company firewall. I search and tried every possible answer but didn't work. Then I tried following and it did work
https://www.calazan.com/how-to-set-the-proxy-settings-in-windows-via-command-line/