# How to set squid for http proxy and make git use it?

Tags: git, proxy, http-proxy, squid

**Intro**
I have an http proxy which has an unusual password with '@' in it. I can't change it. I have to connect to only using the proxy, i.e., every software has to use proxy or they don't work.

**Situation**
I use Ubuntu 16.04.
I have set `gnome settings` proxy with the user-name and password. I have set `/etc/environment` file to specify the http proxy. I have separately set `apt` to use proxy settings.

All the above configurations have something in common, that '@' isn't directly accepted, I had to escape it using **%40**. To pass the proxy username, password, address and port through terminal, I have to use `http://username:password@server:port`. The problem arises here, since most softwares get confused when I write password with @ in it. Something like `pass@word`.

**Problem with git**
[Link to how to make git work with http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14750116/4669984)
I set `~/.gitconf` file as below:

- Case 1:

> [http]
>            proxy = http://user:pass@word@server:port

- Case 2:

> [http]
>            proxy = http://user:pass%40word@server:port

- Case 3:

> [http]
>            proxy = http://user:pass%%40word@server:port

All of which did not work.

---

I used *squidman* in my friend's macOS Sierra to set parent proxy and set git's proxy to use the port squidman is listening to and git worked.

To replicate the same behavior I installed squid in my Ubuntu 16.04.
I have set `squid.conf` file as below:

```
http_port 3128
cache_peer server parent port 0 no-query no-digest login=user:pass%%40word      
#as specified by squid config rules in comments
```

and set git proxy to

```
[http]
    proxy = localhost:3128
```

which still gave me couldn't connect to server

**Question**
How do I properly set Squid proxy?

```
My details for proxy are like (they are invariants):
    Username: user
    Password: pass@54321
    Server: 192.25.5.6 //The server is in my network
    Port: 808
```

How do I make git use of squid's proxy?

---

References are not necessary but would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the git config file is called, ".gitconfig", not ".gitconf" as you mentioned in your question. This might be why your settings did not work as expected