# How to get Git to work through a proxy server

Tags: git, gitlab, debian

I can't execute `git push` or `git pull` commands from my Linux Debian server.

Here is `my /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh`

```
export http_proxy=ip_adress:port
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export dns_proxy=$http_proxy
export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
```

I'm not using any username / password, and the `apt`, `wget` and `curl` commands are working correctly.

My Git commands still returning the following error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'repository_https_url': Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

My `/root/.gitconfig` file content

```
[http]
    proxy = ip_address:port
```

I've even tried with credentials `root:password@ip_address:port` and changed the password special characters like `@` to `%40` but the problem persists.

I already used the `git config --global http.proxy ip_address:port` and also with `username@password` as mentioned above, I'm not finding a solution in the suggested post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pull from a Git repository through an HTTP proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy)

Comment: I already configured the git global `git config --global http.proxy ip_adress:port`

Comment: I tried also with `username@password` nothing changed

Comment: did you try setting environmental variable http_proxy as suggested in the post

Comment: Yes and it's also mentionned in my post the `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh` file content

Comment: In general, your `http_proxy` values and Git configuration settings should be a full URL, not just IP and port.  Some programs may work with that syntax, but not all will.